# How to make a Swing application touchable?

Tags: swing, touch, tablet-pc

We developed a Swing GUI system running on PC, and the boss wants it to run on a special tablet PC too. Does anyone know what else we can do to achieve it? How to make a Swing GUI support touch operation?

The touch-support driver of the tablet PC is necessary, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most touch screens convert touches to mouse events. If yours does so as well you can simply use java.awt.event.MouseListener.